# java.lang.ClassCastException when mapping to Custom Object

Tags: java

I have a collection as shown below:

```
db.testdata.save(
{
    "Indicator": "One",
    "secs": [
        {
            "when": "2013-03-16",
            "num": 16,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "size": "10",
                    "mult": "10"
                },
                {
                    "size": "10",
                    "mult": "10"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "when": "2013-03-22",
            "num": 24,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "size": "100",
                    "mult": "100"
                },
                {
                    "size": "100",
                    "mult": "100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

I am trying to retrieve it using a Custom Object as shown:

```
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("at");
        DBCollection testdata = db.getCollection("testdata");

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("Indicator", "One");

        CustomChainData ocd = (CustomChainData) testdata.findOne(query);

        ocd.getWhen().size();    
    }    
}
```

---

```
import java.util.List;    
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

public class CustomChainData extends BasicDBObject{     
    public CustomChainData() {
        super();
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<WhenData> getWhen() {
        return (List<WhenData>) get("secs");
    }    

    public void setWhen(List<WhenData> expirationDts) {
        put("secs", expirationDts);
    }    
}
```

---

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

public class WhenData extends BasicDBObject{        
    public String getSize() {
        return (String) get("size");
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        put("size", size);
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately I kept on getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.CustomChainData at Test.main(Test.java:19)

Answer (score 6):

The MongoDB Java driver doesn't support automatically using sub-classes of `BasicDBObject`.  That's why you're getting the `ClassCastException`; the objects returned by the driver are `BasicDBObject` instances, not instances of your subclasses.

One option to get this to work would be to replace the casts with constructor calls.  For example, in `Test`, replace

```
CustomChainData ocd = (CustomChainData) testdata.findOne(query);
```

with

```
CustomChainData ocd = new CustomChainData(testdata.findOne(query));
```

and in `CustomChainData`, add

```
CustomChainData(Map m) {
    super(m);
}
```

This uses a copy-constructor to allow usage of your `CustomChainData` class with the data loaded from MongoDB.  However, you'd need to apply this pattern every time you get back a `BasicDBObject` (for the When object as well, for example).

I prefer the approach of using a library that performs mapping between MongoDB data and Java objects.  I've used [Morphia](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/) in the past and been quite happy with it.  Other options are listed in the [MongoDB Java Language Center](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/#pojo-mappers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Object Class type.... Use [setObjectClass](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#setObjectClass(java.lang.Class)) method of [DBCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) before saving and retrieving the object .... In your case, it should be --

***DBCollection testdata = db.getCollection("testdata");
 testdata.setObjectClass(CustomChainData.class);***